# Parsing into a Java ArrayList pair

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a problem in Java that I tried to solve, and until now I can't get it. With this code below I have a response from an XML Parser in the console; it's all in one line like this:

`[359710042040320, Suzuki SX4 "BB71521", 359710042067463, Chevrolet Tahoe Noir "Demonstration", 359710042091273, Isuzu D'Max AA-08612, 359710042110768, Toyota 4 Runner]`

But my objective is to get a response like an ArrayList of pairs, where each Device ID and each Description are together, separated by a comma.

```
(DeviceID)            (Descripcion)
359710042040320, Suzuki
359710042067463, Chevrolet
```

Comment: HashMap<String, String> is a better fit.

Comment: I did all my best to resolve it, but it seems to me so dificult , if someone can help me, i'll very appreciate that. How can i try with HashMap<String, String>?

Comment: I hope that one of these answered your question. If so, we'd appreciate your accepting it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `List<String>` try using a `HashMap<String, String>`.  To define it you would do:

```
HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Then inside your loop replace `result.add(value)` with:

```
result.put(name,value);
```

Now you can access your values from your map via the name(key):

```
result.get(name);//Note Name is a string that holds you key value
```

If you need to see more documentation :[HashMap Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Dott Bottstein said a HashMap might be what you are looking for. I'll use a LinkedHashMap because LinkedHashMaps keep the original order, whereas HashMaps do not guarantee order at all.

Here is what you might do:

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    String deviceID = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    String descripcion = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").toString();
    resultMap.put(deviceID, descripcion);
}

//ok, lets print out what's in the Map
Iterator<String> iterator = resultMap.keySet().iterator(); 
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String deviceID = iterator.next();
    String descripcion = resultMap.get(key);
    System.out.println(deviceID  + ", " + descripcion);
}

Maps have the big advantage that afterwards you can look up a descripcion very quickly if you have the deviceID.
```

---

If you really want an ArrayList you could do it in two ways:

1) an ArrayList of String[] arrays with a length of 2

```
static int DEVICE_ID = 0;
static int DESCRIPCION = 1;

List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    String[] vehicleArray = new String[2];
    vehicleArray[DEVICE_ID] = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    vehicleArray[DESCRIPCION] = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").toString();

    result.add(vehicleArray);
}
```

---

or 2) you could create a class to hold the vehicle data:

```
class Vehicle{

    String deviceID;
    String descripcion;

    public Vehicle(String deviceID, String descripcion){
        this.deviceID = deviceID;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

}
```

And then create a List of Vehicle instances:

```
List<Vehicle> result = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

   String deviceID = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
   String descripcion = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").toString();

    result.add(new Vehicle(deviceID, descripcion));
}
```

---

Finally you might actually like to keep the ID as a long number instead of a String. That's not a problem for the `HashMap` or the `List<Vehicle>` idea, but it wouldn't work with the `List<String[]>` idea. HashMaps work very well with a key that's a Long. The key must be a Long Object, but Java automagically converts from longs to Long objects, so you don't even have to think about it, just set a long primitive as the key and it will work.